# Error with pointer in array

Tags: pointer, compilation-errors

I am currently learning pointers. I am following a book (Says Teach Yourself "Arduino Programming") in which there is an exemple about pointer and array.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  Serial.begin(9600);

  char string1[] = "This is my test string";
  char string2[]="This is another string test";
  char *ptr2 = string2;
  char *ptr1 = string1;

  while (*ptr1 != '\0') { // not "\0"
    *prt2 = *prt1;
    ptr1++;
    prt2++;
  }
  Serial.println(string1);
  Serial.println(string2);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

I get an error "ptr2 was not declare in this scope."

I don't know what is wrong...

That for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the error says p**tr**2 and not p**rt**2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ptr2" != "prt2"

You have a typo there.

Comment: the classical ptr vs prt, cmd vs cnd, cnt vs cmt, cmt vs cmd and so on... :)

Comment: It's teh typical typo :)

Comment: haaa.... Thanks.  I have spent 4 days in a row learning Arduino.... I must be tired. thanks again and sorry for such stupid question. it is working just fine now :-)